# Difference between Passing Instance Data to Vertex Shader methods

Tags: vulkan, directx12

I see two kinds of passing Instance Data to **Vertex Shader** in different Examples.

**1** .Using a **Uniform Buffer** and filling in an array, like below

```
struct UniformBlock
{
    mat4 mProjectView;
    mat4 mToWorldMat[MAX_INSTANCE];
    vec4 mColor[MAX_INSTANCES];
};
```

**2**. Filling in buffers, and then define the buffer as **RATE_PER_INSTANCE**  in vertex layout description (I assume this is the more usual way)

- My Question is :

  - How do these differ from **hardware** or **memory access** Point of View?
  - Are there any cases which one is considered "better" or "faster" than the other?

Comment: Are you asking about Vulkan or D3D12? Because Vulkan doesn't have "rate per instance"; are you talking about instanced vertex arrays?

Comment: I meant VK_VERTEX_INPUT_RATE_INSTANCE @NicolBolas